# How do i add values to my list box while my background proccessing is going on?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am creating an application.and i am scanning files of a drive to search a particular pattern
my progress bar is getting updated and at the end all the file names are listed in the list box.i want the all those files  to be listed immediately as soon as its found that they contain the pattern.

I'm using BackgroundWorker

Comment: What happens if the BackgroundWorker updates the ListBox directly?

Comment: @egruin: exception will happen.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) method in combination with the [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event. This type of scenario is exactly what they are intended for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ReportProgress method of background worker.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement a foreground worker and invoke it from the background worker.

Ideally, you would be passing a list of any newly found files to the foreground worker.